# Microsoft Natural Language List: is there an equivalent to "no language" or "raw unicode" or "Language neutral"?

Tags: sql-server, nlp, full-text-search, tokenize

Is there something equivalent to "non-language" or "raw" in the Microsoft Natural Language List, which would have the effect of causing the word-breaking (i.e. tokenizing) algorithms to use only the space as the delimiter?

Edit: Or is there a way to tell Microsoft's technology to use the period as a token delimiter *only when it is attached to a lexeme*?

The specific problem (for us) is that the full-text search in SQL Server is using the period as a delimiter when tokenizing the text. But our text contains meaningful "non-lexical" character strings like `JC7D.14GR.2345DG` which we would like to search for without searching for each chunk `(JC7D and 14GR and 2345DG)` or `(JC7D NEAR 14GR NEAR 2345DG)` as that separate-chunk approach can yield false positives when these values appear in a list in close proximity to one another.